# How to add an extra value into a Rails param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to solve a problem with getting all the values saved to my database. Here's how my application is setup is

```
before_filter :load_make, only: :create

def create
  @record = @make.message.new(my_params)
  @record.save
end

def load_make
  make_id = params[:message] ? params[:message][:make_id] : params[:make_id]

  @make = Car.find_by(custom_make: make_id)
  @make ||= Car.find_by(id: make_id).tap
end

def my_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:message_type, :message_date, :make_id)
end
```

My problem is that I want to create another method that does a GET request from a different API that returns a created_at date and also save it on `create`, similar to:

```
def lookup_car
  Car.car_source.find(id: my_params[:make_id]).created_at
  # returns a datetime value
end
```

I'm looking for advice on what's the best way to put this into the `my_params` method `:message_date` and save it along with everything else on the `create` action?

Schema for model:

```
create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "make_id"
  t.string   "message",       limit: 255
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "message_type",           limit: 255
  t.datetime "message_date"
end
```

Comment: This has red flags all over it. You're straying far from The Rails Way with your usage of the framework. I'd encourage you to backup a step and reconsider how you can structure your controllers to meet your needs. Remember: a controller is just another object, and objects are pretty cheap in Ruby.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to better refactor this bit of code above? The `lookup_car` method is actually doing an http_request to get an unrelated created_at FYI! @coreyward

Comment: I always advise starting with the excellent [Getting Started on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this pretty late at night when I probably wasn't making much sense, but essentially what I was wanting was to update another value at same time `save` was called on the `@record`. I solved this by using `attributes`, which updates but doesn't call `save` (since I was doing that already below).

For example:

```
def create
  car = Car.car_source.find(id: my_params[:make_id]).created_at
  @record.attributes = { message_date: car }
  @record.save
end
```

Also much thanks to all the other comments. I've completely refactored this code to be more rails idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should NOT really change / update / insert to the `created_at` since Rails does that for you. If anything, I suggest you adding another column.

Secondly, you should NOT do and create / update on a `Get` request.

Other than that, adding another field to your `params` is easy as long as you have that column ready. Not sure how your models are structure, but here you can do something along the line like this below. Let's say you have `message_date` column in your whatever model, you can do this:

```
def my_params
  message_date_param = { message_date: Time.now }
  params.require(:message).permit(:message_type, :message_date, :make_id).merge(message_date)
end
```

Comment: The `created_at` in my example `lookup_car` method is actually doing an http request to something else and pulling in a different, unrelated created_at date, not just Time.now :(. Any suggestions on still adding that other parameter in?

Comment: that's a terrible method name since you might be overriding the rails method (or not depending on how you do that), but you are confusing your team member or anyone who read your code.

Comment: @RobbyWilliams post your model, schema please.

Comment: I've updated the post with the model schema! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm essentially just wanting to do a GET request in another method and also save this when the `create` action is triggered.

Comment: @RobbyWilliams please post your solution. it might help others in the future.